# search for multiple values with LEFT JOINing several tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, left-join, concatenation, group-concat

I have a big problem trying to search for multiple values in MySQL with LEFT JOINing several tables and doing an "all search" with possible extra parameters to filter on. Allow me to elaborate an example case:

I have the following DB structure:

```
wp_posts
id | post_name
--------------
1  | sword
2  | bow
3  | shield

wp_postmeta
id  | post_id   | meta_key  | meta_value
------------------------------------
1   |   1       |   user    | 101
2   |   1       |   power   | 5
3   |   1       |   defense | 0
4   |   1       |   range   | 1
5   |   1       |   condi   | old
6   |   2       |   user    | 102
7   |   2       |   range   | 10
8   |   2       |   condi   | new
9   |   3       |   user    | 101
10  |   3       |   power   | 0
11  |   3       |   defense | 10
```

I'm building a PHP MySQL search with the following:

1) an "all search" input. Search for any `post_name` or any `meta_value`.
2) a filter input to choose the `meta_key` and input the `meta_value`

E.g. search for "sword" filter on `power` = `'5'`

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts as p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE (post_name LIKE '%$search_str%' OR meta_value LIKE '%$search_str%')
/* extra filter */
AND (meta_key = '$filter_key' AND meta_value = '$filter_val')
GROUP BY p.id
```

**MY PROBLEM:**

I always want 1 result per record in `wp_posts`.
But because of my LEFT JOIN every `post_key` and `post_value` will result as a different row.

**So I get nothing if I search for things with multiple filters (on multiple meta_values).**

e.g. search for `old` in all search + filter on `range` = `1`.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts as p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE (post_name LIKE '%old%' OR meta_value LIKE '%old%')
AND (meta_key = 'range' AND meta_value LIKE '%1%')
GROUP BY p.id
```

→　0 results...

So I know the reason but I don't know a good workaround...
I know I can e.g. group concat columns, but then I cannot keep the meta_key and meta_value as sets right? Any ideas on a good way to do this?

*(wait until you hear the problem I'm having adding a 3rd table with tags and adding that to my all-search box.......)*

Comment: When you use multiple filters, you expect to get one row? or a row for each filter?

Comment: I want to keep the `GROUP BY p.id` so I want 1 result always. No matter how many filters.

Comment: Not sure I'm following , you said `i get nothing if i....` if you what? post an example where you get nothing, and the actual data that you expect to get.

Comment: Updated the question with the example query.

Comment: Yea I see, and now, which row do you expect to get? id 4 or id 5? Or a combination?..

Comment: I want to see id 1, 'sword' from wp_posts. Because it's old and has a range of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an [exists subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) to get around this problem:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts as p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pm ON p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE (post_name LIKE '%old%' OR meta_value LIKE '%old%')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta pm2 WHERE pm2.meta_key = 'range' AND pm2.meta_value LIKE '%1%' and pm2.post_id=pm.post_id)
GROUP BY p.id
```

But be aware, that your query depends on the full group by sql mode not being set. This sql mode is now on by default in the newer versions of mysql.

Comment: What do you mean by "But be aware, that your query depends on the full group by sql mode not being set. This sql mode is now on by default in the newer versions of mysql."

Comment: If this sql mode is set, your query will produce a syntax error because it is agsinst the sql standards.

Comment: What do you mean by "the sql mode is set" ?

Comment: My SQL mode was not set. So that's a good thing in this case right?

Comment: Why not just use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Why would you say that's better than grouping by?

Comment: @Shadow I don't understand why you need this line: `pm2.post_id=pm.post_id`

Comment: @mesqueeb, `DISTINCT` is what you really mean even though it would do the same. And you'll not care about sql mode.

Comment: @Shadow Now I have a problem with a table connected through a double LEFT JOIN... If you do have some spare time, could you have a quick look?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246152/using-mysql-exists-with-double-left-join-using-a-join-table
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two `EXISTS()` conditions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts p
WHERE (post_name like '%old%'
       or EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta p2 WHERE p.id = p2.id AND p2.meta_value LIKE '%OLD%'))
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta p3 WHERE p.id = p3.id AND p3.meta_value LIKE '%1%' AND p3.meta_key = 'range')
```

Comment: In the MySQL guide they use `SELECT *` in the "exist queries", why would you use `SELECT 1` instead?

Comment: @mesqueeb it does not matter what is in the select list of an exists subquery. If you check out my solution, then you can see that I also used 1 and not *.

Comment: @mesqueeb "MySQL ignores the SELECT list in such a subquery, so it makes no difference"

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution, which is (IMHO) closer to your original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_posts as p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm1 ON p.id = pm1.post_id
LEFT  JOIN wp_postmeta as pm  ON p.id = pm.post_id
WHERE (p.post_name LIKE '%old%' OR pm.meta_value LIKE '%old%')
AND   (pm1.meta_key = 'range' AND pm1.meta_value LIKE '%1%')
-- GROUP BY p.id
```

I use another (INNER) JOIN to filter by the must-have-condition *range LIKE '%1%'*. I was not sure about how it would perform, but could not find a reason, why it should do worse.

I expect MySQL first to search `pm1` for `meta_key = 'range'` (which should be indexed), look if `meta_value LIKE '%1%'`, if so - find the related post. If `post_name LIKE '%old%'` select the post row, if not - search all related rows from `wp_postmeta` for `meta_value LIKE '%old%'`. If found a row - skip searching (because of `DISTINCT`) and select the post row. If not skip the post row.

It might even perform better, because you skip all posts that do not have a "range" at all.