# Finding posts with tag1 AND tag2? (using a join-table) Exists / Having / subqueries... What to use?

Tags: mysql, left-join, exists

I need to make a query to search and filter on multiple terms.

I have a table with weapons and all can have multiple tags. **I want to be able to create a filter option for the user that shows only weapons with e.g. 'tag1' AND 'tag2'.**

Until now:
I was filtering them using a `GROUP_CONCAT` with `HAVING` until now but this has performance issues! As I am forced to do a `GROUP BY w.id` But I want to do `ORDER BY` something else. And GROUP BY doesn't play nicely with ORDER BY....

I tried to create something with EXISTS (SELECT …) to be able to filter on multiple values, however I’m not sure to do this when there is a “join-table” in the middle… (so with 2 left joins)

```
weapons:
id | name
----------
1  | sword
2  | shield

weapon_tag_links:
tag_id  | weapon_id
-------------------
62      | 1
80      | 1
80      | 2
60      | 2

weapon_tags:
tag_id | tag
--------------
60      | red
62      | blue
80      | old
```

**Search query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM weapons as w
LEFT JOIN weapon_tag_links AS l ON l.weapon_id = w.id 
INNER JOIN weapon_tags AS t ON l.tag_id = t.tag_id 
WHERE EXISTS (
    ****** Something to go here *******
    WHERE t.tag = ‘blue’
) AND EXISTS (
    ****** Something to go here *******
    WHERE t.tag = ‘old’
)
```

I’m just missing the link you need in `EXISTS`. But I’m not sure how to add this…

**The Question:**

Say I want to search for a record in weapons that is `blue` AND `old`, (a sword in this case) how do I do this?

**I'm not saying I MUST use "EXISTS" but I want the best optimised way to search for posts with certain tags connected by `AND`!**

Comment: What result do you want to obtain, more precisely please ?

Comment: Search for e.g. All wp posts with the terms 'blue' and also other terms depending on which filters the user choses

Comment: why a `left join` then ? why not an `inner join` instead ?

Comment: @Stan my search query can be launched even if no search terms are put in. That omits the WHERE and EXISTS parts. But i still need data from the joined tables if there is any to be found. That's why i need a left join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id 
WHERE p.id IN 
(
    SELECT p2.id FROM wp_posts AS p2
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr2 ON p2.ID = tr2.object_id 
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS t2 ON tr2.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_id 
    GROUP BY p2.id
    HAVING FIND_IN_SET('blue', GROUP_CONCAT(t2.term)) AND FIND_IN_SET('old', GROUP_CONCAT(t2.term))
)
```

Comment: This searches for BLUE OR OLD tag, not AND.

Comment: I want to try and avoid having to use GROUP BY, that's why I wanted to try and solve it with 'EXISTS'. (I'm not sure why you got downvoted though. This did give me a correct result)

Comment: This also works! But somehow I cannot use DISTINCT with this query... =(
I never knew it was so difficult to select posts with 2 tags or more... I've actually been doing it with group_concatting them into a string and checking that string with "HAVING" but since it forces me to use GROUP BY I wanted to change it. Because GROUP BY together with ORDER BY on a different field is so slow!

Comment: thanks for your help. Sorry I marked it correct many years later. Your upvote on my question is much appreciated!! : D

Answer (score 0):

Turn it around.  That is start with `tag IN ('blue', 'old')` in the innermost subquery.  From that, find the `tag_ids`.  From them, find the `weapon_ids` `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`.  Last, in the outermost query, get the `weapon.name`.

No `EXISTS()`.  No `LEFT JOINs`; I'm not sure you needed `LEFT` in the first place.

Your original attempt needed to join to `tag` twice with different aliases.  I avoid that by using the `IN` and `HAVING`.

**More**

Yeah, that gets a bit tricky...

```
SELECT
     FROM  
      ( SELECT  weapon_id
            FROM  weapon_tags
            JOIN  weapon_tag_links USING(tag_id)
            WHERE  tag IN ('blue', 'old')
            GROUP BY  weapon_id
            HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2 
      ) a
    JOIN  weapons w ON w.id = a.weapon_id;
```

It would be easier if you had not normalized tags.

Comment: Dear Rick James. Thank you for your answer! I'm going to try it out. I have never used `IN` before so I hope I can figure it out!

Comment: I found out that IN can be used for many "OR"s but I want `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: I tried this, but it gave me 0 results:
`SELECT * FROM weapon_tags as t
INNER JOIN weapon_tag_links AS l ON l.tag_id = t.tag_id
INNER JOIN weapons AS w ON l.weapon_id =  w.id 
WHERE tag IN ('blue', 'old')
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`

Comment: I think I wasn't able to write the MySQL query you described correctly. Could you write an example for me? I'm not sure what you mean with "from that" and "from them". Is my above query mistaken?